# How do I receive multiple answer inputs from a user and convert them to a score that can be used to determine what message is shown?

Tags: python

I'm very new to programming and I'm trying to give myself projects to work through. The first one is a stock screener where the program asks the user questions about a stock and gives it a score out of 4. Depending on what the score is the program will return the total score.

I wrote the function below. When I call it the result is always 0 despite answering "yes" to questions.

```
def stock_score_calc(score):
    print("Has the company had at least 3 years of rising profits?")
    answer_1 = input(" ")
    if answer_1.lower == "yes":
        score += 1
    elif answer_1.lower == "no":
        score += 0
    print("Has the company had at least 3 years of rising sales?")
    answer_2 = input(" ")
    if answer_2.lower == "yes":
        score += 1
    elif answer_2.lower == "no":
        score += 0
    print("Has the company had at least 3 years of rising sales?")
    answer_2 = input(" ")
    if answer_2.lower == "yes":
        score += 1
    elif answer_2.lower == "no":
        score += 0
    print("Has the company had at least 3 years of rising sales?")
    answer_2 = input(" ")
    if answer_2.lower == "yes":
        score += 1
    elif answer_2.lower == "no":
        score += 0
    return score
```

To call I run this code:

```
score = 0
print(stock_score_calc(score))
```

Comment: what is the use of `score += 0`, fix your indentation

Comment: `answer_2.lower` is a function.  You are not calling the function, you are referencing the function.  A function is never equal to "yes".  You need `answer_2.lower()`.  And you don't need ANY of the `elif` clauses.  Just delete them.

Comment: Try replacing `lower` with `lower()` everywhere.

Comment: Thank you all! I adjusted all this and it works fine now. Such simple things I just need to learn. Hopefully I get good enough to help out one day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by @Tim Roberts and others the root problem in your code is the lines containing x.lower should contain x.lower() because the .lower() is a function not an attribute of the string object. Be that as it may, your code can be vastly improved by taking advantage of standard python data structures as illustrated below:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Question = namedtuple("Question", ['txt', 'rsp', 'score'])   #Creates easy to use tuple with named elements

def stock_score(quiz_list: list) -> int:
    # asks series of questions defined in quiz_list and returns a score
    score = 0
    for q in quiz_list:
        answ = input(q.txt).lower()
        if answ[0] == q.rsp[0]:
            score += q.score
    return score

# List of important questions, expected answers and score upgrade
questions = [Question("Has the company had at least 3 years of rising profits?  ", 'yes', 1),
           Question("Has the company had at least 3 years of rising sales?  ", 'yes', 1),
           Question("Has the company had at least 3 years of rising sales?  ", 'yes', 1),
           Question("Has the company had at least 3 years of rising sales?  ", 'yes', 1)]
```

Now running `print(stock_score(questions))` yields:

```
Has the company had at least 3 years of rising profits?  y
Has the company had at least 3 years of rising sales?  y
Has the company had at least 3 years of rising sales?  y
Has the company had at least 3 years of rising sales?  y
4
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the comments above appeared to fix but I really like your creative solution. I have never heard of that module before so it's helpful to learn how it is applied :)

Comment: You could justr as easily used a standard tuple instead of the namedtuple Question.  This would mean that where I have written q.txt, you would replace it with q[0], q.resp with q[1], and q.score with q[2].  Using the indexing however is less readable than using the namedtuple.